# How to parallelize this piece of code?

Tags: python-2.7, random, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, embarrassingly-parallel

I've been browsing for some time but couldn't find any constructive answer that I could comprehend.

How should I paralellize the following code:

```
import random
import math
import numpy as np
import sys
import multiprocessing

boot = 20#number of iterations to be performed
def myscript(iteration_number):  
    #stuff that the code actually does


def main(unused_command_line_args):
    for i in xrange(boot):
        myscript(i)
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

or where can I read about it? I'm not really sure how to search for it even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's pretty much a natural progression from a for loop to parallel for a batch of embarrassingly parallel jobs.

```
>>> import multiprocess as mp
>>> # build a target function
>>> def doit(x):
...   return x**2 - 1
... 
>>> x = range(10)
>>> # the for loop
>>> y = []   
>>> for i in x:
...   y.append(doit(i))
... 
>>> y
[-1, 0, 3, 8, 15, 24, 35, 48, 63, 80]
```

So how to address this function in parallel?

```
>>> # convert the for loop to a map (still serial)
>>> y = map(doit, x)
>>> y
[-1, 0, 3, 8, 15, 24, 35, 48, 63, 80]
>>> 
>>> # build a worker pool for parallel tasks
>>> p = mp.Pool()
>>> # do blocking parallel
>>> y = p.map(doit, x)
>>> y
[-1, 0, 3, 8, 15, 24, 35, 48, 63, 80]
>>> 
>>> # use an iterator (non-blocking)
>>> y = p.imap(doit, x)
>>> y            
<multiprocess.pool.IMapIterator object at 0x10358d150>
>>> print list(y)
[-1, 0, 3, 8, 15, 24, 35, 48, 63, 80]
>>> # do asynchronous parallel
>>> y = p.map_async(doit, x)
>>> y
<multiprocess.pool.MapResult object at 0x10358d1d0>
>>> print y.get()
[-1, 0, 3, 8, 15, 24, 35, 48, 63, 80]
>>>
>>> # or if you like for loops, there's always this…
>>> y = p.imap_unordered(doit, x)
>>> z = []
>>> for i in iter(y):
...   z.append(i)
... 
>>> z
[-1, 0, 3, 8, 15, 24, 35, 48, 63, 80]
```

The last form is an unordered iterator, which tends to be the fastest… but you can't care about what order the results come back in -- they are unordered, and not *guaranteed* to return in the same order they were submitted.

Note also that I've used `multiprocess` (a fork) instead of `multiprocessing`… but purely because `multiprocess` is better when dealing with interactively defined functions.  Otherwise the code above is the same for `multiprocessing`.